# Delete records from multiple table in postgres database sql script

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have a scenario as below.

I have five tables: `merchants`, `user_details`, `user_role`, `transient_payments` and `payments`.

Requirements: if merchant_id does not exist in transient_payments and payments table then that merchant should be deleted from `merchants`, `user_details`, `user_role`

My Query :

```
DELETE FROM m,ud,ur USING merchants 
       INNER JOIN user_details 
       INNER JOIN user_role 
       where merchant_id not 
       exists (select * 
               from transient_payments 
               full join payments 
               on transient_payments.merchant_id = payments.merchant_id );
```

> ```
> Error :ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: DELETE FROM m,ud,ur
> USING merchants INNER JOIN user_details ...
>                     ^
>
> ********** Error **********
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "," SQL state: 42601 Character: 14
> ```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45007359/330315