# Delete a record if the associated Join entry does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to delete a record from a table if the parent table record does not exist.

The table in question are `merchants` and `merchant_configurations`

merchant_configurations has a `foreign key`(**merchant_id**) reference to merchant table `primary key` (**id**)

Here how the 2 tables looks

```
== merchant_configurations
  id           integer
  merchant_id  integer
  config_options  hstore
```

Merchant table

```
== merchants
  id integer
  name string
```

Now, select query to retrieve all those merchant_configurations record for whose merchant record is delete look like this

```
select merchant_configurations.id from merchant_configurations LEFT JOIN merchants ON merchant_configurations.merchant_id = merchants.id where merchants.id IS NULL
```

Now, I essentially want is to delete all those record but for some reason

```
DELETE merchants_configurations from select merchant_configurations.id from merchant_configurations LEFT JOIN merchants ON merchant_configurations.merchant_id = merchants.id where merchants.id IS NULL
```

Does not seem to work.

The only way I manage to get it done using WITH clause.

```
WITH zombie_configurations AS (
   select merchant_configurations.id from merchant_configurations LEFT JOIN 
   merchants ON merchant_configurations.merchant_id = merchants.id where 
   merchants.id IS NULL 
)

DELETE from merchant_configurations where id IN (select id from zombie_configurations);
```

Now my question is:

Is it possible to delete the Record using normal way without having to do the `WITH` clause and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`, it is simple and efficient:

```
SELECT FROM merchant_configurations mc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM merchants m
                  WHERE mc.merchant_id = m.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `USING`:

```
DELETE FROM merchant_configurations AS mc
USING merchant_configurations AS mc2
LEFT JOIN merchants ON mc2.merchant_id = merchants.id
WHERE mc2.id = mc.id AND merchants.id IS NULL
```